# How can I check only existence in z3?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I need some temporary variables in z3, I don't need the value to be calculated just need to check it exists is enough.

This is (simple form of) what I'm working on:

```python
import z3

def maj(a, b, c):
    return (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c)

def func(a, b, c):
    a = z3.RotateRight(a, 5) ^ z3.BitVecVal(0xafaf, 16)
    b = z3.RotateRight(b, 2) ^ z3.RotateRight(b, 7)
    c = z3.RotateRight(c, 11) ^ z3.LShR(c, 3)
    return a + c, b + c, maj(a + b, a + c, b + c)

solver = z3.SolverFor('QF_BV')
some_var = 0x0000
_x = z3.BitVec('x', 16)
x = _x
y = z3.BitVecVal(some_var, 16)
c = z3.BitVec('c', 16)
for i in range(16):
    x, y, c = func(x, y, c)
solver.add(c == z3.BitVecVal(0xff00, 16))
print(solver.check())
model = solver.model()
print(model[_x].as_long())
```

I need value of `x` but don't need value of `c` just knowing there is some variable is enough.
If I pass some fixed constant for `c` it runs much faster (but it might be `unsat`)

Also using `z3.Var(1, z3.BitVecSort(16))` gives `unknown` as answer.

Is there any way for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous: I take it that you *do* care that the final value of `c` to be `0xff00`, but you don't care what its initial value is? Since you keep mutating `c`, it isn't clear which one you want to constrain.

If that's the case, i.e., if you want the final value of `c` to be `0xff00` and don't care what the initial value is, then what you did is just fine. You just shouldn't expect the solver to come up with a solution quickly. This looks a lot like some sort of encryption/scrambler routine, and SMT solvers--or any other solver for that matter--isn't good at dealing with such problems by design. They tend to encode one-way functions, so you shouldn't expect an out-of-the-box general constraint solver to reverse-engineer it with ease. It can be done, but it won't be fast.

In the off-chance that you actually don't care what the **final** value of `c` is (which is an odd thing to do, but I suppose there might be a use case for it), then the typical way to deal with this would be to use a quantifier. It kind of follows from your requirement: "There is some `c`, I don't care what it is." So, let's code that. We need to make a few changes. First, we need quantifiers, so set the solver appropriately:

```py
solver = z3.SolverFor('BV')
```

Then:

```py
final_c = z3.BitVec('final_c', 16)
solver.add(z3.Exists([final_c], c == final_c))
```

Note that the declaration of `final_c` is a technicality. You won't be able to access its value. It's just to make sure that there exists some final value of `c` that's reachable. (i.e., the whole thing isn't `unsat`.)

With these changes, if you run the program you'll see it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leventerkok/qq/b.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(model[_x].as_long())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'as_long'
```

This is because the model didn't even care for `_x`; it noticed that this is satisfiable and didn't bother to compute `_x`. But we can ask it to give us a value like this:

```py
model = solver.model()
print(model.evaluate(_x, model_completion=True))
```

This prints:

```
sat
0
```

So, there's a way to run your equations and it all works out starting with `x = 0`. Well, that wasn't very interesting, but without any additional constraints it does make sense: Starting with `x = 0`, and an appropriate `y/c`, you can indeed unroll this calculation.

Finally, don't use `z3.Var(1, BitVecSort(16))`. Those are lambda-vars, that you should never reach out for. (It's a design flaw in my mind that z3 exposes them to the end-user, but not everything is perfect!)

Comment: I think you have misread the code - the `c` in that line is not the same `c` that is declared as a variable. The `c` in that line is some derived value which depends on both the original variable `x` and the original variable `c`.

Comment: @kaya3 Right you are, I did indeed. I'll post an updated answer soon.

Comment: @kaya3 Hopefully this version answers the question. It's still an odd thing to do what the OP is asking for; I suspect there's more to the story here that's not communicated in the original question.

Comment: I interpreted the question differently - I think the `z3.BitVecVal(0xff00, 16)`constraint *is* a specific value and OP does care about that value in the constraint, but OP doesn't care about what value the original `c` variable might have in a solution. Probably OP thinks it might be more efficient to solve for x than to solve for both x and c, though my intuition says there's probably not much difference. But I could be wrong both about my interpretation of the question and about that intuition.

Comment: That makes sense; If the final value of `c` supposed to be `0xff00`, then what he/she wrote originally is the way to go about it. And no, it won't be fast; as the solver needs to "undo" the calculations and that's an expensive thing to do.

Comment: Added an update to clarify the point about the final value of `c` vs. the initial. I suspect you are right; i.e., that's what the OP intended. But no, there's no way to make it "go fast."

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes as you stated what I expect is that final value equals `0xff00` but don't care about initial value and I was looking for a way to make it faster (as there are many possible values for `c` but don't care about them, just initial x is important and giving an initial value for `c` leads to a very much faster computation)
Thanks for your answer